# How to output multiple values being stored into an array using a for loop on the same line?

Tags: java, for-loop, output

I created my arrays and when I am entering the values for the arrays, they are being shown on separate lines for example...

Enter the values for the first array: 75
48
23

I would like the numbers to be shown on the same line and not sure how to do it.  Thank you for your help.

```
public class CompareArrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arraySize;

        System.out.print("Enter the array size: ");
        arraySize = input.nextInt();

        int[] array1 = new int[arraySize];
        int[] array2 = new int[arraySize];

        System.out.print("Enter the values for the first array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the values for the second array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array2[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        if(Compare(array1, array2)) {
            System.out.println("Judgement: \t The arrays are identical");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Judgement: \t The arrays are not identical");
        }
        input.close();
    }

    public static boolean Compare(int[] array1, int[] array2)
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if(array1[i] != array2[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When in the console inputting those values you are hitting enter which is why it looks like it is on different lines. If you want to input the values on 1 line you could possibly input them as a string and split it.

If you're looking to just print the array on one line you can do that with a basic for loop and using System.out.print().

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
}
```